# Python - Multiple "private" implementations for a class

Tags: python, class, oop, implementation

I have a public class which the module exports, and 3 implementations of it.

At certain points in the program, the implementation used will be changed dynamically,
something along the lines of:

```
class PublicClass(object):

  _IMPLEMENTATION_TO_USE = _Imp1
  def func1(self, arg1): 
    _IMPLEMENTATION_TO_USE.func1(arg1)

class _Imp1(PublicClass):
  def func1(self, arg1): pass

class _Imp2(PublicClass):
  def func1(self, arg1): pass
```

What's the best (Pythonic) way of achieving it?

Comment: This is pretty much what regular inheritance does. Why wrap an implementation instead of just returning an object of type `_Impl1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of composition, you could consider using a [Abstract Base Class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html), with three different subclasses.
In python, [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) is favoured over explicitly checking types.